# react-native 0.57.4, `_typeof3 is an instance of Object` error

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I followed [instruction steps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) to start a new project with react-native v0.57.4.

With everything installed correctly (I've re-checked a few times),
I create native project with `react-native init MyProject`.
but then I got this error after build iOS project:

```
Unhandled JS Exception: _typeof3 is not a function
(In '_typeof3(typeof Symbol === "function" ? Symbol.iterator : "@@iterator")',
'_typeof3' is an instance of Object)
```

[image]

Did anyone have experience on this? Thanks.

Comment: May I know if you create using `react-native init` or?

Comment: @Isaac yes, with `react-native init`. I also modified my question about it. thanks

Comment: Can you check which `build system` are you using in XCode? Go to `Xcode -> File -> Workspace settings -> Build System` and check if you're using Legacy Build System or New Build System

Comment: That is standard one. I attached image inside question

Comment: Ok, change it to Legacy and killed your simulator, and re run your app

Comment: Wait, are you sure that you're in "Workspace settings"? Because it should be "Shared Workspace Settings" instead

Comment: I don't see workspace settings with XCode 9.4.1, there is only `Project Settings` right after `Save as Workspace`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182703/discussion-between-val-and-isaac).